# Best practice for handling commands from command line C#

Tags: c#, command-line-interface

I am creating a program for working with a database. I am interested in which is the best way to handle and execute commands like 
`insert ...`
`remove ...`
`update ...`

I mean, should I make a class for `Command` or `switch`/`if` would be enough? Or maybe some other approaches exist to do this?

Comment: 1 method for 1 command....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should definitely create one class per command. There is [Command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) which I believe you'll find useful.

There are also some libraries which make parsing command line easier, for example [Command Line Parser Library](http://commandline.codeplex.com/).